# Understanding How to Apply UItableview and UITableViewDataSource Methods Based on Apple's Documentation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, apple-documentation

I'm currently going through a tutorial on `UITableView`.  While learning I'm attempting to understand how the `UITableView` should be constructed by following Apple's documentation and its programming guides.  In the tutorial, the developer places the `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` method inside of the `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method which belongs to the datasource.  As a newcomer after reading Apple's references and guides, I would not have guessed that the `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` method goes inside of the `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method.  As a developer, how do you pick up on subtle things like this?  Is it because the `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method returns a `UITableViewCell` and may be the best place to do `UITableViewCell` configurations?

I'd like to gain a better understanding of Apple's references for future projects, thank you in advance for any comments or answers.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath)

        return cell

}
```

Comment: Only because it returns `UITableViewCell`

Comment: @abndsr Thank you.  Would it be safe to assume that this is how majority of Apple's API's work in order to customize apps?  The general idea being to subclass objects, customize them to our liking, and then plug them into the necessary places for them to be called?